# Laravel Installing Blade and npm run dev Fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, npm-install, wsl-2

I'm new to Laravel development, using a Windows machine. I've finally set up WSL2 and started trying to do the Chirper example they have on the site.

When I try to run the following command, I get errors:

```
php artisan breeze:install blade
```

It doesn't like that:
[image]

I've not been able to figure out a way around this. Some of the examples I've found in other sources suggested running `npm install` as a step to begin resolve it, but that also doesn't work:

[image]

The relevant parts of the error log mentioned in that screenshot are here:

```
713 info run esbuild@0.17.12 postinstall node_modules/esbuild node install.js
714 info run esbuild@0.17.12 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
715 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 2092ms
716 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
717 timing command:install Completed in 7498ms
718 verbose stack Error: command failed
718 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:53:27)
718 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
718 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
718 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
719 verbose pkgid esbuild@0.17.12
720 verbose cwd \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\joe\workspace\chirper
721 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
722 verbose node v18.12.1
723 verbose npm  v9.1.2
724 error code 1
725 error path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\joe\workspace\chirper\node_modules\esbuild
726 error command failed
727 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
728 error '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\joe\workspace\chirper\node_modules\esbuild'
728 error CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
728 error UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
728 error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
728 error   throw err;
728 error   ^
728 error
728 error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\install.js'
728 error     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
728 error     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
728 error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
728 error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
728 error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
728 error   requireStack: []
728 error }
728 error
728 error Node.js v18.12.1
729 verbose exit 1
730 timing npm Completed in 7549ms
```

I've spent 10 hours of my weekend trying to get Laravel set up to a state where I can just...go. This has been a painful use of a weekend and I still can't find a way to resolve it. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Turns out my answer below resolved the Blade installation, but the issues with `npm run dev` are still there. For those who were asking, yes, I'm literally running this out of the terminal I open by clicking the Ubuntu shortcut in Windows.

It now gives me the following:
[image]

**EDIT 2**
It looks like I needed to run it as a super user. `sudo npm run dev` gives me the following screen:
[image]

Comment: Try install using just `php artisan breeze:install`

Comment: It also gives me the same sort of error as what's shown in the screenshots @PunitGajjar

Comment: what are your node & npm versions ?

Comment: Node - v12.22.9, NPM - 9.1.2

Comment: How are you starting that WLS2 session? Are you using the command prompt and running `wsl`? Are you directly using `Windows Terminal`?

Comment: I'm trying to run the command through the terminal for the Ubuntu version I installed @matiaslauriti

Comment: so you are literally opening `Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows` through the shortcut, right?

Comment: Holy moly, I figured it out. Give me a second and I'll write up how I solved it.

Comment: Now `npm run dev` is having issues, but that gets me past what I've posed about here.

Comment: @matiaslauriti original post updated with an edit. I was able to install blade, but I still can't do `npm run dev`

Comment: I've updated node. `sudo n lts` - It says v18.15.0 is now installed.

When I check `node -v`, it shows v12.22.9, though

Comment: ...it looks like if I preface the npm command as `sudo npm run dev`, I get something that look good? 

Answer (score 2):

*I figured it out*

It turns out I didn't have NPM installed. I had to do a few things to get this working.

First, it turns out I didn't have NPM installed. I had to run the following commands to resolve this:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Finally, after those were completed, I was able to run `php artisan breeze:install`.